# Convert exponential format into number

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel sheet cell =326/86400 is returning 0.003773148

In VBA ?326/86400 is returning 3.77314814814815E-03

I need the value returned in the cell using VBA.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the cell using `NumberFormat`.  In this example C2 = 326 and D2 = 86400.  Cell A1 will display your answer of .00373148

```
Sub CalcWithFormat()
 'You custom VBA calculation
  Range("A1").Formula = "=C2/D2"

 'Format the cell
  Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```

If you need to apply the formatting to the entire column change to:

```
 'Format Range
  Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"
```

If you need to define the number of decimals you would need this:

```
'Format Range
 Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0.000000000"
```

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I did not want the output in an Excel cell. However, your decimal number format at the end of the post was the pointer I was looking for.